# Não é possível encontrar o controle com atributo de nome não especificado no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-6, angular-7

Estou tentando fazer um componente simples utilizando Reactive Forms no input, porem esta dando erro que até o momento não tinha visto

**Input.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder,Validators, AbstractControl } from 
       "@angular/forms"
@Component({
  selector: 'nube-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})

export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() itens?:string

 @Input() inputFormsGroup?:FormGroup


 constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.inputFormsGroup = this.inputFormsGroup ||
   this.formBuilder.group({})
   for(const inputItens of this.itens){
    const control = this.formBuilder.control({
    name:['',Validators.required]
  })
  this.inputFormsGroup.addControl(inputItens, control)
  }
 }

}
```

**Input.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="inputFormsGroup">
 <input type="text" [formControlName]="item">
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'nube-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
 })
export class AppComponent {
title = 'Nube';
formGroup? : FormGroup
checkInput:string
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
}
ngOnInit() {

this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({});
this.checkInput = 'Teste'
}
```

}

**App.component.html**

```
<nube-input [inputFormsGroup] [itens]="checkInput"></nube-input>
```

**App.module.ts**

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

 import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
 import { InputComponent } from './input/input.component'; 
 import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   InputComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

**Erro**

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
at _throwError (forms.js:2144)
at setUpControl (forms.js:2052)

atFormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular
    /forms/fesm5/forms.
    js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5281)
at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5
/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5882)

at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5
/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5803)


at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21996)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23264)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23226)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23860)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23820)
```

Onde eu posso estar errando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro informado é que na inicialização do seu componente você informou que deveria existir um controle chamado 'name' no formulario, porem não existe nenhum controle com esse nome no HTML do seu componente.

```
<form [formGroup]="inputFormsGroup">
 <input type="text" [formControlName]="item">
</form>
```

Por:

```
<form [formGroup]="inputFormsGroup">
 <input type="text" formControlName="name">
</form>
```

Claro que percebi que sua intenção é gerar algo como input dinâmicos, mas acredito que compreendendo melhor o porque deu erro, você já vai conseguir seguir.

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é:

Você chama o **[formControlName]="item"** no **html** mas o **item** não está declarado no **ts**.

**Declare o formControl corretamente e chame no html corretamente.**

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Complementando a resposta dos colegas, esse erro também acontece se tu esquece de colocar o nome na tag. Ex:

```html
<input type="text" name="prazo" formControlName="" class="input">
```

Ou seja, se ele não acha o nome do campo que está no arquivo TS ou tem um nome no HTML diferente do arquivo TS, esse erro aparece.